# Akka Streams binary decoder

Tags: scala, stream, akka, codec

I would like an example of how to write a binary decoder for Akka Streams. I have a file of binary data. The data consists of a 20 byte header in which the last 2 bytes contain a length field, followed by 'length' bytes. So, if the last two bytes contain `0x00`,`0x10` then the message consists of a 20 byte header and a 16 byte body. I would like to extract the 36 bytes and pass it on down stream, then extract the next binary message, and so forth and so on.

I suppose I want to use `FileIO.via()` but I am at a loss as to how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: This is not really a high quality question in that it doesn't show a lot of work/info in what you have tried and what did not work.  You should read the streams docs on the Akka site, and look for usage of the `Framing` class (http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/?_ga=1.8421173.147353783.1450706988#akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing$) and see if you can figure it out from there.

Comment: I have read the documents. They show examples of working with data that have delimiters such as new lines. Documents also refer to solutions using deprecated PipeLines.

Comment: Look at the scaladoc link I provided for the `Framing` class and se if you can get something to work using `Framing.lengthField`

Comment: @Aamir, i am having the same problem right now, hence i wonder if you fine a way ?